# Show that a vector field is complete

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Show that if $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ is a positive and proper function and $X$ is a vector field such that $\langle df,X\rangle $ is bounded, then $X$ is complete.

I know that if $X$ is a vector field with compact support, then it is complete, but i do not know how to use the fact that $\langle df,X\rangle $ is bounded.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought about going back to the definition and proceeding by contradiction? (It then reduces to a local question in $\Bbb R^n$, and maybe some ODE estimates will jump out at you.)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for your help. Do you mean, suppose that $X$ is not complete, then exists $p\in M$, such that $I_p\neq\mathbb{R}$ then there is $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p\not\in D_t:=\{q\in M,t\in I(q)\}$. But i do not know how to continue.

Comment: I'm thinking in proving that $Supp(X)$ is the pre image of a compact subset of $R$, then cause $f$ is proper, $Supp(X)$ is compact. Or maybe try to proof that $Supp(X)$ is bounded. But i still do not know how to continue,

Comment: Are you familiar with the [escape lemma](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5_9.pdf) (Lemma 9.19)? Roughly speaking, integral curves which escape in finite time cannot be contained in a compact subset. It is very closely related to your question through a contradiction argument. The proof is left as an exercise in the linked document, but it seems to follow from local existence and uniqueness of integral curves.